# VimのdelimitMateでpythonの複数行文字列リテラルを補完する

Tags: python, vim

VimのdelimitMateをつかってpythonの複数行文字列リテラルを補完したいのですが、普通の文字列リテラルの入力だと認識されてしまいうまく補完ができません。
どうすればいいのでしょうか?
smartquoteあたりを変更するのでしょうか?

```
a = """|  #この時点で(")を3文字分補完してほしい
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の設定でご希望の動作になります。

```
autocmd FileType python let b:delimitMate_nesting_quotes = ['"',"'"]
```

また、Markdown等でバッククォート（`）で同様のことをしたい場合は

```
autocmd FileType markdown let b:delimitMate_nesting_quotes = ["`"]
```

でできます。

必要に応じて`augroup`などを設定してください。詳細は `help 'delimitMate_nesting_quotes'` をご参照ください。